# convert time in javascript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

How do I convert 09:00:00 to this 9:00 in javascript? or vice versa. I have a GUI in google app script where someone enters the time and I need it to look normal for them.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
var timestring = '09:00:00';
var timechunks = timestring.split(':');
var newdata= parseInt(timechunks[0],10)+':'+timechunks[1];
console.log(newdata);//9:00
```

Comment: You also misspelled parseInt, but the missing radix was a no-no :) - now vice versa

Answer (score -3):

I would suggest you to use [Datejs](http://www.datejs.com/). Something like this should do the trick:

```
Date.parse('09:00:00').toString('HH:mm')
```

Comment: that would be a GIGANTIC overhead to handle 6 lines of JS

Comment: It won't work as the built in Date.parse() method fails to parse a string with time only and the method cannot be changed. Otherwise this would work without Datejs using `Utilities.formatDate(new Date(Date.parse('09:00:00')), 'GMT', 'HH:mm')`